# how to link to a nested route path inside a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have stories and substories. Substories are nested inside stories and on the **stories`index.html.erb`**. I'm looping trough all the stories, and inside I'm looping through all the substories.

here is the code:

```
<% @stories.each do |story| %>
  <%= story.title %>
  <%= story.plot %>

  <%= link_to 'Show', story_path(story) %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_path(story) %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", story_path(story), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>

  <% story.substories.each do |substories| %>
    <%= substories.title %>
    <%= substories.subplot %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Story', new_story_path %>
```

This works fine, but I want to link to the edit page of each substory by passing the following argument inside the second loop:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_substory_path(substory.story, substory) %>
```

I get a `NameError in Stories#index` `undefined local variable or method 'substory'`, however this work fine in the **substories `index.html.erb`** file.

I've also tried the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_substory_path(@substory.story, @substory) %>
```

for which I get a `NoMethodError in Stories#index` `undefined method 'story' for nil:NilClass`

Here are my routes models and controllers:

```
#routes.rb
  resources :stories do
    resources :substories
  end

#story.rb
has_many :substories

#substory.rb
belongs_to :story
```

**stories_controller.erb**

```
  before_action :set_story, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @stories = Story.all
  end

  def show
    @substories = Substory.where(story_id: @story.id).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @story = Story.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @story.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Story was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: root_path }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: root_path.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @story.update(story_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Story was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: root_path }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @story.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @story.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to stories_url, notice: 'Story was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_story
      @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    end

    def story_params
      params.require(:story).permit(:title, :plot)
    end
```

**substories_controller.erb**

```
before_action :set_substory, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_story

  def index
    @substories = Substory.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @substory = Substory.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @substory = Substory.new(substory_params)
    @substory.user_id = current_user.id
    @substory.story_id = @story.id
    if
      @substory.save
        redirect_to @story
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @substory.update(substory_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Story was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: root_path }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @story.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @substory.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def set_story
      @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    end

    def set_substory
      @substory = Substory.find(params[:id])
    end

    def substory_params
      params.require(:substory).permit(:title, :subplot)
    end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% story.substories.each do |substory| %>
    <%= substory.title %>
    <%= substory.subplot %>

    <% if substory %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_substory_path(substory.story, substory) %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

You just made a typo. @substory would work too if you declare it on your Stories#index

Comment: I'm also trying to add this in the first loop: `<%= link_to 'New substory', new_story_substory_path(substory.story, substory) %>` can't seem to be able to make it work.

Comment: The problem would be the first loop does not know what a substory is, unless you define it in the Stories#index which would make it `@substory`

Also, in your current index.erb, you are not really making use of most things in you substories_controller.rb.

Comment: How would I define it in the Stories#index?

Comment: ```
class StroriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @stories = Story.all
    @substory = SubStrory.find params[:some_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: I've passed `@substory = Substory.find(params[:story_id])` argument inside the stories#index. I've tried this before and i'm getting a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` `Couldn't find Substory without an ID` although I checked in rails console all my substories have a story_id.

Comment: I made a separate question for this