# How to link to a nested route action inside a parent loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display everything on my index page, but when I try to link to a new_story_substory_path I get undefined local variable or method substory.

Here is the code:

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @stories.each do |story| %>
  <h3><p><%= story.title %></p></h3>
  <p><%= story.plot %></p>

  <% if story.user == current_user %>
    <%= link_to 'Show XXX', story_path(story), class: "btn btn-success" %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_path(story), class: "btn btn-success" %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", story_path(story), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-success" %></br>
  <% end %>

  <% story.substories.each do |substory| %>
    <h4><p><%= substory.title %></p></h3>
    <p><%= substory.subplot %></p>

    <% if story.user == current_user %>
      <%= link_to 'Show', story_substory_path(substory.story, substory), class: "btn btn-default" %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_substory_path(substory.story, substory), class: "btn btn-default" %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", story_substory_path(substory.story, substory), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <br>

  <% if story.user == current_user %>
    <br>
    <br>
    # this is where I'm getting the error:
    <%= link_to 'New subplot', new_story_substory_path(substory.story, substory), class: "btn btn-warning" %>
    # however if I move this up, inside the second loop, it works perfectly.
    <br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Story', new_story_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

Here is my controller, routes and models:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_story, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @stories = Story.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @story = current_user.stories.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @story = current_user.stories.build(story_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @story.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Story was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: root_path }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: root_path.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @story.update(story_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Story was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: root_path }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @story.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @story.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to stories_url, notice: 'Story was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_story
      @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    end

    def story_params
      params.require(:story).permit(:title, :plot)
    end
end
```

---

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :stories do
    resources :substories
  end

  root 'stories#index'

end
```

---

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :substories, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user
end

class Substory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :story
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :stories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :substories, dependent: :destroy
end
```

---

what am I missing?

Edit:

Here is the controller for the substories:

```
class SubstoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_substory, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_story

  def index
    @Substories = @story.substories.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @substory = Substory.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @substory = Substory.new(substory_params)
    @substory.user_id = current_user.id
    @substory.story_id = @story.id
    if
      @substory.save
        redirect_to @story
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @substory.update(substory_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Story was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: root_path }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @story.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @substory.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def set_story
      @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    end

    def set_substory
      @substory = Substory.find(params[:id])
    end

    def substory_params
      params.require(:substory).permit(:title, :subplot)
    end
end
```

Comment: At the line producing the error: You are calling the `substory` variable but it is only existing in the `story.substories.each` loop ; you probably meant to use `new_story_substory_path(story)` (path leading to the creation page of a substory belonging to the story currently been seen/edited)

Comment: Do you have a separate controller for substories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to link to a nested route path inside a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419525/how-to-link-to-a-nested-route-path-inside-a-loop)

Comment: @BroiSatse I added the code from the substories controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the comments.

MrYoshi wrote:

At the line producing the error: You are calling the substory variable but it is only existing in the story.substories.each loop ; you probably meant to use **new_story_substory_path(story)** (path leading to the creation page of a substory belonging to the story currently been seen/edited)

Basically I changed the line form:

```
<%= link_to 'New subplot', new_story_substory_path(substory.story, substory), class: "btn btn-warning" %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to 'New subplot', new_story_substory_path(story), class: "btn btn-warning" %>
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to put this as a comment but I need 50 reputation points to do so. Anyway here is my solution:

The problem is index.html comes from Stories Controller. At this point, you are actually not using any other controllers. This is a common problem at a single page application using ROR. Things do get messy this way.

And you are right, you have to move your error on the second loop. The problem is it would show more than once. That is because there is more than one story. If you want to avoid this, the solution I would say is just make an stories#show show.html.erb. Once you click story, it directs to substroy which then has a plot.

Comment: I'm trying to display everything on my index page, read the first line of my post. Thanks for trying to answer, I figured it out eventually from the comments.